# Flash builder/AS3 unique device ID for mobile apps

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

is there a unique device ID that I can use in Flash Builder/AS3 to differentiate between devices in a Flex mobile project?

I am trying to circumvent having to code a login/registration system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to write a Native Extension to access a mobile device ID.  Long term I suspect you'll be better suited w/ a login/reg system. So that someone can,f or example, use the same app w/ the same settings on their tablet and their phone [and their laptop].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique ID's are no longer available in iOS 5, so your best approach is to create a unique ID for each device the first time the application launches.  You can use the Encrypted Local Store to save this value if you are using AIR 3 or greater.

You can use a utility like this one to create a unique ID: http://old.nabble.com/Generating-Random-Unique-ID-td21303353.html